# Only last sub-string being testing in java for loop

Tags: java, string, loops, substring

I am creating a loop that will test each substring of a user input to test for illegal characters. However, it only detects when the illegal character is in the last position of the input. I feel as if the solution may be simple but I cannot seem to figure it out, how can I correct this so it will detect it at any position in the string?

```
public class IllegalFileName {

public static final Set<String> illegalCharsSet = new HashSet<String>(
        Arrays.asList("/", "\n", "\r", "\t", "\0", "\f", "`", "?", "*",
                "\\", "<", ">", "|", "\"", ":", ".", "£", "$", "%", "^",
                "&", ")", "("));

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String illegalNameText = "££!233";
    String illegalNameText2 = "££!233$";
    boolean illegalName = false;

    for (int i = 0; i <= illegalNameText.length() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (illegalCharsSet.contains(illegalNameText.substring(i))) {
            System.out.println(illegalNameText + " is illegal");
            illegalName = true;
            System.out.println(illegalNameText.substring(i));
        }

    }

    for (int i = 0; i <= illegalNameText2.length() - 1; i++) {
        System.out.println(i);
        if (illegalCharsSet.contains(illegalNameText2.substring(i))) {
            System.out.println(illegalNameText2 + " is illegal");
            illegalName = true;
            System.out.println(illegalNameText2.substring(i));
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`substring(i)` returns a substring from `i` included to `n` excluded (where `n` is the size of the initial string).

Use a set of chars instead (`Set<Character>`, initialized by `Arrays.asList('/', '\n', ...)`, and use `contains` on `theString.charAt(i)`.

Answer (score 1):

You want to check **if it contains an illegal character**, thus one of `illegalCharsSet`. I think it should be like that:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= illegalNameText.length() - 1; i++) {
    System.out.println(i);
    if (illegalNameText.contains(illegalCharsSet.get(i)) {
        System.out.println(illegalNameText + " is illegal");
        illegalName = true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would simply iterate through the illegal characters and then do

```
if (illegalNameText.contains(illegalChar)) {...
```

or similar. A more concise solution might be to use [Java regular expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) and do something like.

```
if (Pattern.matches("[£$%]", illegalNameText)) {...
```

substituting in your full set of illegal characters. You might want to pre-initialise/compile that regexp above for efficiency's sake.